# What is the status of Vim keybindings in MonoDevelop?

Tags: vim, ide, monodevelop

There seems to be a lot of conflicting information regarding Vim keybindings in MonoDevelop. Does anyone know whether this feature is available or what the current status is? I know there was progress being made at some point.

Comment: Based on jamessan's answer I downloaded the latest trunk build, which has rudimentary VI mode support. Looking good so far. http://monodevelop.com/Download/Trunk_Builds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basics work pretty well. It currently supports the following modes: Normal, Visual, Visual Line, Insert, Overwrite. In those modes, most of "single-key" commands are supported, and some slightly more complex commands work too, such as searching and marks.

The major limitation right now is that it does not support multi-character text operators and text objects. I started implementing support for that a while back but it isn't finished yet. Assistance would be welcome.

Comment: Any status on vim mode? there's like 300+ forks, is one of them further along than others?

Comment: @thatmiddleway 6 years after post and still nothing in the default dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you check their [site](http://monodevelop.com/), you can see that [Vi Mode](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Tasks/Source_Editing/Vi_Mode) is a section of their [TODO](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/TODO).

Comment: It makes sense now that I look again. I was confused by this post: http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2008/10/14/vi_modes_monodevelop